# reactjs error- TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import styles from './Statewise.css';

const Statewise = () => {

    const [data, setData]=useState([]);
     
    const getCData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json');
        const actualData = await res.json();
        console.log(actualData.Statewise);
        setData(actualData.Statewise);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
       getCData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="bts">
            <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
                <div className="main-heading">
                    <h1 className="mb-5">
                        <span className="font-weight-bold">INDIA COVID 19 TRACKER</span>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div className="table-responsive">
                    <table className="table table-hover">
                        <thead className="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>States</th>
                                <td>Confirmed</td>
                                <td>recovered</td>
                                <td>death</td>
                                <td>active</td>
                                <td>updated</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                               data.map((curElem) => {
                                      return(
                                          <tr key={curElem.id}>
                                              <th>{curElem.state}</th>
                                              <td>{curElem.Confirmed}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.recovered}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.deaths}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.active}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.lastupdatedtime}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                      )
                                })
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Statewise;
```

Not able to extract values from the api.

1. I have tried data && data.map(... this is also not working.
2. I have tried adding the load and error methods but then also the main data from the api id not displayed.
   please suggest solutions .

Comment: Render is working before the async completed. Your data is null at the moment. You need to check if data exist only then map will work e.g.

{data && data.length > 0 && data.map((curElem)

Comment: What is inside you data.json ?

Comment: https://api.covid19india.org/data.json  its the api that have information related to covid cases in Indian states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `actualData` does not contain `Statewise` field but it does contain `statewise` (See difference in `s` in both fields)

So to solve this just replace `Statewise` with `statewise`

```
const getCData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json');
    const actualData = await res.json();
    setData(actualData.statewise);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `data` in you HTML you can make a conditional statement to be sure that your data are loaded.

For exemple :

```
     {
                             data ?  data.map((curElem) => {
                                      return(
                                          <tr key={curElem.id}>
                                              <th>{curElem.state}</th>
                                              <td>{curElem.Confirmed}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.recovered}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.deaths}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.active}</td>
                                              <td>{curElem.lastupdatedtime}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                      )
                                      : <p> No data available </p>

                                })
                            }
```